# Manifolds of Non-Standard Dimension

Tags: logic, set-theory, manifolds

Can there exists (non-trivial) manifolds of non-standard dimensions? Certainly, there do exist manifolds of dimension $n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (as well as manifolds of countably many dimesnions). However, manifolds are not "first-orderizable" and hence we cannot use the compactness theorem here.

**Hunch**: I think that if $D$ is a non-principal ultrafilter, $I$ is countable, and if we let $\mathfrak{A_i} \models$ **ZFC**, then we will find manifolds of non-standard dimensions in $\prod_D \mathfrak{A}$.

**Question**: If this hunch is correct, how do we prove the existence of (non-trivial) manifolds in such a model? More concretely, if $n$ is a non-standard natural number, can we prove the existence of an $n$-sphere?

**Edit: Question 2**: Would $(S^1,S^2,S^3,...)\in \prod_D\mathfrak{A}$ be an $(1,2,3,4,...)$-sphere or a different (1,2,3,4,...)-manifold?

Comment: What do you mean by non-standard?

Comment: @user161825: Sorry, by non-standard, I mean non-standard natural number. In $\prod_D \mathfrak{A}$, the element $(1,2,3,4,...)$ is a non-standard "natural number".

Comment: The answer is yes: It is a theorem that for all $n$ there is an $n$-sphere. This also holds in your ultrapower.

Comment: The *$D$-equivalence class* of $(S^1,S^2,\dots)$ is obviously an $n$-sphere, where $n$ is the $D$-equivalence class of the sequence $(1,2,3,\dots)$. This is just [Łoś's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct#.C5.81o.C5.9B.27s_theorem).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Oh right, since manifolds can be described in $L=\{\in \}$. Thank you.